# Apply the script on two groups of layers

Tags: pyqgis, layers

I have two groups of layers, and I'm applying the same processing script to each of them, Is there any way to include the two groups in one script rather than repeating the script?

```
#find group
from datetime import date
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group = root.findGroup("RL")
layers = [layer.layer() for layer in group.children()] 

merged = processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers",
            {'LAYERS': layers, 'OUTPUT':"TEMPORARY_OUTPUT"})["OUTPUT"]

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(merged, False)
root.insertLayer(0, merged)

provider = merged.dataProvider()

## add date field
i = merged.fields().indexFromName("date")
if i == -1:
    provider.addAttributes([QgsField('date', QVariant.Date)])
    merged.updateFields()

## populate date field
i = merged.fields().indexFromName("date")
attr_map = {f.id(): {i: QDate(date.today())} for f in merged.getFeatures()}
provider.changeAttributeValues(attr_map)

## delete some fields
field_names = ['X','Y','rotation','path'] # field names to be deleted
field_indices = [merged.fields().indexFromName(f) for f in field_names]
provider.deleteAttributes(field_indices)
merged.updateFields()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make a list of the group names then iterate through it

```py
from datetime import date
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()

group_names = ['group1', 'group2']

for name in group_names:          # iterate through names
    group = root.findGroup(name)  # the current group name from the list
    layers = [layer.layer() for layer in group.children()]

    merged = processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers",
            {'LAYERS': layers, 'OUTPUT':"TEMPORARY_OUTPUT"})["OUTPUT"]

    merged.setName('merged ' + name)  # use the group name to make a unique name for the output, otherwise it will be overwritten

    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(merged, False)

    root.insertLayer(0, merged)

    provider = merged.dataProvider()

    ## add date field
    i = merged.fields().indexFromName("date")
    if i == -1:
        provider.addAttributes([QgsField('date', QVariant.Date)])
        merged.updateFields()

    ## populate date field
    i = merged.fields().indexFromName("date")
    attr_map = {f.id(): {i: QDate(date.today())} for f in merged.getFeatures()}
    provider.changeAttributeValues(attr_map)

    ## delete some fields
    field_names = ['X','Y','rotation','path'] # field names to be deleted
    field_indices = [merged.fields().indexFromName(f) for f in field_names]
    provider.deleteAttributes(field_indices)
    merged.updateFields()
```

Comment: It gives me only the merged layer of the second group

Comment: Did you make the unique name like I suggested in the comment?

Comment: yes, I did. I just changed the name of the second group in group_names

Comment: It's working now bro! thank you so much. It saves me a lot of time, I'm grateful to you.

Comment: when I tried the whole script it apply changes only on the second merged layer. I'm trying to figure it out but with no result

Comment: For me it works fine. I just tested using my own data. Are you sure you have included the line where the unique layer name is made? `merged.setName('merged ' + name)`

Comment: the first part works fine, but the second part -adding and removing columns- works only on the second merged layer

Comment: I just tested fully again and it works absolutely fine. Adding the date field and removing the other fields. Do all your layers have the fields you are trying to remove? It seems there is a different issue with your data

Comment: the layers have the same fields, but it still applies only to the second merged layer. could you please write the whole script you have just tested in your answer?

Comment: My guess is that you did not indent the rest of the script so it was not part of the loop

Comment: yes, that's It. primitive mistakes. Thank you so much bro!